# Is there a 32-bit version of 2.76?

Tags: windows

I'm new to Blender and I have just dopwnloaded Blender 2.76.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work under my 32 bits Windows7.

Is there a 32-bit version of 2.76?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome John :) Yes, blender supports win7 32bit. All packages are listed here: http://www.blender.org/download/. If a problem occurs, then make sure it's really a bug and please report it: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports. Enjoy blender.se!

Comment: Thank you! I followed the link you gave and I've downloaded the 32 bit version. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Great John! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

As others also said, yes, and more: there here are **two** 32bit windows versions: a .msi (installer) and a .zip (archive). You could detail more what is "not working" for you, and any error messages you get, that would help understand what is causing your Blender to not work.

As an advice, since installing .msi can have issues sometimes, try the .zip version, it should work out of the box, just unzip it anywhere ad launch the blender.exe inside. If that blender works, it's just the .msi install process having issues of some kind...